# Using setImageDrawable dynamically to set image in an ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget

I am generating a string from database dynamically which has the same name of image in `drawable` folder.

Now I want to set that value for `ImageView` using `setImageDrawable(R.id.StringGenerated)` dynamically.

Any Suggestions..

Comment: means you are generating ID of the image dynamically, right?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try this,

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + StringGenerated, null, null);
```

This will return the id of the drawable you want to access...
then you can set the image in the imageview by doing the following

```
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton..i found it somewhere else bt still thanks for your Efforts.. :)

Comment: However using setImageResource()  "does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup ... consider using setImageDrawable() or setImageBitmap()." _(Android documentation)_

Comment: You could also get the id by simply using: R.drawable.filemane

Answer (score 108):

```
Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
            imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
            imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
```

or

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

Comment: he said he is generating a string from database dynamically with the same name of image.

Comment: getDrawable(R.drawable.icon) is deprecated

Comment: For people who need to resolve getDrawable(R.drawable.icon) is deprecated, try to read this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

Answer (score 26):

The resource drawable names are not stored as strings, so you'll have to resolve the string into the integer constant generated during the build.  You can use the `Resources` class to resolve the string into that integer.

```
Resources res = getResources();
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(
   generatedString, "drawable", getPackageName() );
imageView.setImageResource( resourceId );
```

This resolves your generated string into the integer that the `ImageView` can use to load the right image.

Alternately, you can use the id to load the `Drawable` manually and then set the image using that drawable instead of the resource ID.

```
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable( resourceId );
imageView.setImageDrawable( drawable );
```

Comment: @Greyson... Nice one sir..thatz what i am looking for..Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 20):

You can try to use this code:

```
ImageView ImgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImgView);
ImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myicon);
```

Answer (score 14):

As simple as this answer:

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic);
imageview.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 12):

All the answers posted do not apply today. For example, getDrawable() is deprecated. Here is an updated answer, cheers!

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, drawable)
```

From documented method

> public static final android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   getDrawable(@NotNull android.content.Context context,
>   @android.support.annotation.DrawableRes int id

Comment: Thanks for mentioning deprecated part.

Answer (score 9):

This works, at least in Android API 15

```
ImageView = imgv;
Resources res = getResources(); // need this to fetch the drawable
Drawable draw = res.getDrawable( R.drawable.image_name_in_drawable );
imgv.setImageDrawable(draw);
```

You could use setImageResource(), but the documentation specifies that  *"does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup ... consider using setImageDrawable() or setImageBitmap()."* as stated by chetto

Answer (score 5):

If You cannot get Resources object like this in a class which is not an Activity, you have to add getContext() method for getResources() for example

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
int id = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 5):

`imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable));`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use something like:

`imageView.setImageDrawable(ActivityCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),
                    R.drawable.generatedID));`

or using Picasso:

`Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.generatedId).into(imageView);`

Answer (score 1):

From API 22 use:

```
Drawable myDrawable =  ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
                        R.drawable.dos_red, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I did the following to solve it:

```
**IMAGEVIEW**.setImageResource(getActivity()
             .getResources()
             .getIdentifier("**IMG**", "drawable", getActivity()
             .getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a POJO.java class and create "constructor, getter & setter methods"

```
class POJO{
        public POJO(Drawable proImagePath) {
                setProductImagePath(proImagePath);
        }

        public Drawable getProductImagePath() {
                return productImagePath;
        }

        public void setProductImagePath(Drawable productImagePath) {
                this.productImagePath = productImagePath;
        }
}
```

Then setup the adapters through image drawable resources to CustomAdapter.java

```
    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<POJO>{

       private ArrayList<POJO> cartList = new ArrayList<POJO>();
       public MyCartAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
          super(context, resource);
       }

       public MyCartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<POJO> cartList) {
          super(context, 0, cartList);
          this.context = context;
          this.cartList = cartList;

       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          /*
          *Here you can setup your layout and references.
          **/
          ImageView productImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cart_pro_image);
          productImage.setImageDrawable(POJO.getProductImagePath());
        }
    }
```

Then pass the references through ActivityClass.java

```
public class MyCartActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
       POJO pojo;
       CustomAdapter customAdapter;
       ArrayList<POJO> cartList = new ArrayList<POJO>();

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

          customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, cartList);

          pojo = new POJO(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.help_green));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use **setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)**. example:

```
ImageView iState = findViewById(R.id.imageview_state);
if (isOk){
    iState.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.outline_ok));
}else{
    iState.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.outline_no));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

a piece of my project, everything works! )

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ModelSystemTraining modelSystemTraining = items.get(position);

int icon = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(modelSystemTraining.getItemIcon()), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        final FragmentViewHolderSystem fragmentViewHolderSystem = (FragmentViewHolderSystem) holder;
        final View itemView = fragmentViewHolderSystem.itemView;
//                Set Icon
fragmentViewHolderSystem.trainingIconImage.setImageResource(icon);
//                Set Title
fragmentViewHolderSystem.title.setText(modelSystemTraining.getItemTitle());
//                Set Desc
fragmentViewHolderSystem.description.setText(modelSystemTraining.getItemDescription());
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself  - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Answer (score -4):

The 'R' file can not be generated at the run time of the app. You may use some other alternatives such as using `if-else` or `switch-case`

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to the question. It seems as though he's trying to set an imageview to an already existing resource, rather than trying to generate `R` again