# How to change ImageView source in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

This is my xml, this is located inside a fragment that appears in my activity.

```
<FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/whoamiwith"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/default_image" />
                </FrameLayout>
```

And this is my java code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View click) {
    if (click == profileBtn) {
        whoamiwith.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_i_wanna_put);
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the image source of the image view. There are no syntax errors but when I click the button the emulator is giving me a force close and on the logcat it says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

It's pointing to the line:

```
whoamiwith.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbtn);
```

Comment: You need to check like click.getId() == profileBtn. And share your code how you initialize your whoamiwith ?

Comment: have you initialized your `whoamiwith` ?

Comment: There is a problem with your initialization. Check your imageview id.

Comment: ImageView whereami = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whereami); i got it this way guys..

Comment: How you dealt with "whoamiwith" You have only initialized whoamiwith rite? How about whereami? and you are trying to set background image with initializing that!

Comment: you have declared the imageview as whereami & you are setting the background image on whoami. Recheck your calling variables.

Comment: im sorry that was a FAIL question i edited the code and now that should help you understand the problem.

Comment: this force close is really bugging me all day. and by the way, the <FrameLayout> is located on a fragment which appears on my activity, i think that might be one of the reason. dont you think guys?

Comment: Show me initialication line for whoamiwith

Comment: did u initialise like... ImageView whoamiwith = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.whoamiwith)..it is saying whoamiwith is null, i think..

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
whoamiwith.setImageResource(R.drawable.loginbtn);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
 ImageView whoamiwith = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.whoamiwith)  
 Drawable new_image= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbtn);   
    whoamiwith.setBackgroundDrawable(new_image);
```

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable is now deprecated unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

Just try

```
ImageView whoamiwith = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.whoamiwith)  
whoamiwith.setImageResource(R.id.new_image);
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize image view :

```
whoamiwith = findViewByid(R.id.whoamiwith);
```

Then on Click method, write this lines to change the image resource  :

```
 if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
    {
        // for API above 15
        whoamiwith.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbtn));
    }
    else
    {
        // for API below 15
        whoamiwith.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loginbtn));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ImageView whoamiwith = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.whoamiwith);
whoamiwith.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_i_wanna_put);
```

Comment: Shots fired. HAHA

Answer (score 2):

Exception is `whoamiwith` is null.
did u initialise `whoamiwith` like,
ImageView whoamiwith = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.whoamiwith)

Refer [Using setImageDrawable dynamically to set image in an ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642823/using-setimagedrawable-dynamically-to-set-image-in-an-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, we can change ImageView programmatically like this.

```
val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename)
```

And in Java,

```
ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
```