# AssetManager and InputStream for ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

This is the part of my function that assigns an image to my ImageView.  I can not get it to show an image.  I have my files listed under assets/signs/"image names."  This code came straight from my textbook with some minor tweaks to fit my code. I appreciate the help.

```
String nextImage = signNames.remove(0);
AssetManager assets = getAssets();
InputStream stream;
    try{
         stream = assets.open("signs/"+nextImage + ".gif");
         Drawable sign = Drawable.createFromStream(stream,nextImage +".gif" );
         signImageView.setImageDrawable(sign);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
         Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " +nextImage, e);
    }
```

Comment: your signImageView is indeed an ImageView?

Comment: you have to use the help of movie class to play gif in image view here  this link http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-and-how-to-use-animated-gifs/

Comment: Yes it is an ImageView. I've tried changing them to jpeg's, still nothing.  I tried:
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + nextImage, null, null);
signImageView.setImageResource(id);
and nothing

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a much simpler idiom for what you are trying to do. No need to stream the image the want to display. Simply put the image in `res/drawable` (or `res/drawable-hdpi`, etc). Then simply:

```
 signImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage)
```

Of if you need to get the resource from a dynamic string:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + nextImage, null, null);
signImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage)
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642823/using-setimagedrawable-dynamically-to-set-image-in-an-imageview)

This assumes your signImageView is indeed an `ImageView`.