# How to transform uri to integer for drawable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, widget, drawable

I am working on widgets and i need to use this views.setImageViewResource method in AppWidgetProvider but this method wants integer
but i have uri how can i solve this problem?

```
class AppWidgetBroadcast : AppWidgetProvider() {
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var mydatabase: FirebaseDatabase

override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray
) {
    // Perform this loop procedure for each widget that belongs to this
    // provider.
    appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
        // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity.
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            /* context = */ context,
            /* requestCode = */  0,
            /* intent = */ Intent(context, WidgetDetailsActivity::class.java),
            /* flags = */ PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        // Get the layout for the widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button.
        val string="sa"
        val uri:String="myUri"
        var imageuri: Uri = Uri.parse(uri)
        val views: RemoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName,R.layout.activity_widget_details).apply {
            setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.fullImageWidget, pendingIntent)


        }



        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current
        // widget.
        //views.setImageViewUri(R.id.fullImageWidget,null)

        views.setImageViewUri(R.id.fullImageWidget,imageuri)
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use views.setImageUri(). Ofcourse you cannot convert an uri to a resource integer.

Comment: its not working

Comment: What is 'not working'? Show your code. Views.setImageDrawable().

Comment: i edit my Question and there is no method called imageView.setImageDrawable()

Comment: "myUri" is not a valid uri. And we still dont know the meaning of 'not working'.

Comment: I know i am retriving uri from firebase database i just dont want to show details about uri

Comment: I try to mean when i say 'not working' i am doing everything fine when i use views.setImageViewUri is not working but when i user setImageViewResources my code is working

Comment: You do not have to post the details of your firebase uri if you post you firebase uri

Comment: Not working? What happens instead? Errors? Exceptions? If it contained already an image then is it erased? Not working? What is not working?

Comment: widget image doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Uri is of this type: `android.resource://your.package.name/drawable/drawable_name`

So you use this code in your project. It will help you.

```
public Drawable getDrawableFromUri(Activity activity, Uri uri) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            return Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, uri.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**OR**

If your Uri is of this type: `https://url.image.jpg`

So you use Glide library in your project for load Image.

- build.gradle

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
}
```

- activity.java

```java
 String URL = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1162019476/tr/fotoğraf/oyuncak-yarış-arabasında-boy-ve-köpek.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=TxRP45SO7Eja8IKQ0KFqHZAbzXuvWWVD3sLsQUpSc-A="

 Glide
    .with(YOUR_CONTEXT)
    .load(URL)
    .into(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW);
```

Comment: views.setImageViewResource method is want Integer from me so this is not working becasue its drawable

Comment: you must me use `imageView.setImageDrawable();` instand of `views.setImageViewResource();`

Comment: There is no method called imageView.setImageDrawable()

Comment: then you must be convert drawable to int you will found on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642823/using-setimagedrawable-dynamically-to-set-image-in-an-imageview

Comment: Can i removing the activity input and replacing it with context? And What should I write in the name input in the link you sent?

Comment: And my uri is this type https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1162019476/tr/foto%C4%9Fraf/oyuncak-yar%C4%B1%C5%9F-arabas%C4%B1nda-boy-ve-k%C3%B6pek.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=TxRP45SO7Eja8IKQ0KFqHZAbzXuvWWVD3sLsQUpSc-A=

Comment: This is url of image if you want to show your image in imageview then use Glide library for image loading.

Comment: Or you can also use image after download in your devices storage

Comment: Yes you can replace with context